# Pasar una variable en lugar de un where &nombrevariable

Tags: php, mysql

Mi consulta es la sgte. se puede poner una variable dentro de una consultala variable $talla es la que quiero poner dentro de mi consulta dentro del while

```
 $ok = "false";
    $codigo = $datos[0];
    $talla = $datos[1];
    $existencia = $datos[2];

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total_registro FROM Prueba " . "WHERE codigo_articulo='" . $codigo."'";
    $rs = $this->consulta($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $total_registro = $row["total_registro"];
        error_log($total_registro);
        if ($total_registro == 0) {
            $sql = "insert into prueba("
                . "codigo,"
                . "$talla"
                . ") "
                . "values(?,?)";
            error_log(&sql)
            $stmt = $this->consulta_prepared($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $datos[0], $datos[2]);
            $stmt->execute();
            if ($stmt) {
                $ok = "true";
            }
        } else {


        }
    }
    $arr = array('ok' => $ok);
    return ($arr);
```

Comment: $sql = "insert into prueba("
                . "codigo,"
                . "$talla"
                . ") "
                . "values(?,?)"; en donde dice talla es donde nose como llamar a la variable si podrias darme un ejemplo

Comment: `$sql = "insert into prueba(codigo,".$talla.") values(?,?)";`

Comment: gracias ya funciona DarkFenix

Comment: @DarkFenix Publiquen una respuesta con la solución y marquen como solucionado para que pueda servir a otros usuarios en un futuro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de añadir una variable a un query es concatenar **correctamente** dicha variable, para tu ejemplo será

```
$sql = "insert into prueba(codigo,".$talla.") values(?,?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

las variables dentro de los strings en PHP funcionan de distinta manera si encierras tu string con comillas simples a si las encierras con comillas dobles.

**Comillas simples**

Con las comillas simples estás forzado a cerrar tu string y concatenar el comando/variable que quieres usar:

```
$variable_de_prueba = 'roja';

echo 'Prueba de variable $variable_de_prueba solo como muestra';
//Prueba de variable $variable_de_prueba solo como muestra

echo 'Prueba de variable ' . $variable_de_prueba . ' solo como muestra';
//Prueba de variable roja solo como muestra
```

**Comillas dobles**

Las comillas dobles por el contrario, te permiten introducir las variables **directamente** en el string sin tener que terminarlo y concatenarlo:

```
echo "Prueba de variable $variable_de_prueba solo como muestra";
//Prueba de variable roja solo como muestra

echo "Prueba de variable " . $variable_de_prueba . " solo como muestra";
//Prueba de variable roja solo como muestra
```

Tomando esto en cuenta, el código:

```
$sql = "insert into prueba(" . "codigo," . "$talla" . ") " . "values(?,?)";
```

Está concatenando strings en comillas dobles así que **si estás incluyendo esa variable en tu query**. Otras formas de escribir el mismo query son:

```
$sql = "insert into prueba(codigo,$talla) values(?,?)";
$sql = "insert into prueba(codigo," . $talla . ") values(?,?)";
$sql = 'insert into prueba(codigo,' . $talla . ') values(?,?)';
```